# How to join 2 collections in mongoose using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose-schema

I want to join two collection using mongoose nodejs but i am stuck,

[collection1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfU8S.png)

[collection2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8ONB.png)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const gameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    providerName:{
        type: String
    },
    gamesSettings :[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'games_setting'
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('gamesDetails', gameSchema);

This is the route : 

router.get('/', async (req, res)=>{


    try {
        const gamesDetails1 = await joinCollection.find();
        res.json(gamesDetails1);
        //res.render('./games/gamesetting', { data: gamesDetails1 });
    } catch (e) {
        res.json({ message: e });
    }

});
```

I am getting null in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understood your question correctly but I'm thinking that what you need is to execute a query where you get gameeSetting populated. The answer to that would be:

```
const details = await gamesDetails.find().populate('gamesSettings');
```

Comment: my question is i have two collection A and B and i want to join collection A with collection B , so how can i achieve this?